# How to know the features of python package?

Tags: python, package, pypi

I'm working on optimization problem for my project. To develop in python language, several packages are available like mealpy, pyswarm, etc.
I've downloaded these packages but unable to know the exact features of these packages. For example, mealpy package has several algorithms, so how to write a cost function and how to access various algorithms for the same cost function?

Answer (score 4):

Once you've imported any module, you can do this

```
help(module_name)
```

you can get the documentation of all the functions present in that module. you can also do this

```
dir(module_name)
```

this will simply list the names of all the functions and variables defined in the module.

Answer (score 3):

In jupyter there is a cool trick once you imported the module where you can add a question mark in the beginning. This gives you a brief description with it's main functionality:

```
import pandas as pd

? pd
```

> ```
> **pandas** is a Python package providing fast, flexible, and expressive data
> structures designed to make working with "relational" or "labeled" data both
> easy and intuitive. It aims to be the fundamental high-level building block for
> doing practical, **real world** data analysis in Python. Additionally, it has
> the broader goal of becoming **the most powerful and flexible open source data
> analysis / manipulation tool available in any language**. It is already well on
> its way toward this goal.
>
> Main Features
> -------------
> Here are just a few of the things that pandas does well:
>
>   - Easy handling of missing data in floating point as well as non-floating
>     point data.
>   - Size mutability: columns can be inserted and deleted from DataFrame and
>     higher dimensional objects
>   - Automatic and explicit data alignment: objects can be explicitly aligned
>     to a set of labels, or the user can simply ignore the labels and let
>     `Series`, `DataFrame`, etc. automatically align the data for you in
>     computations.
>   - Powerful, flexible group by functionality to perform split-apply-combine
>     operations on data sets, for both aggregating and transforming data.
>   - Make it easy to convert ragged, differently-indexed data in other Python
>     and NumPy data structures into DataFrame objects.
>   - Intelligent label-based slicing, fancy indexing, and subsetting of large
>     data sets.
>   - Intuitive merging and joining data sets.
>   - Flexible reshaping and pivoting of data sets.
>   - Hierarchical labeling of axes (possible to have multiple labels per tick).
>   - Robust IO tools for loading data from flat files (CSV and delimited),
>     Excel files, databases, and saving/loading data from the ultrafast HDF5
>     format.
>   - Time series-specific functionality: date range generation and frequency
>     conversion, moving window statistics, moving window linear regressions,
>     date shifting and lagging, etc.
> ```

But as other users already mentioned it's better when you google the documentation which provides you with some examples.